# How to check if the user is authorized to view a particular article?

Tags: articles, acl, authentication

How can I check if the user has access to any particular article?
I was looking at $user->authorise() method but it looks like it's only for core edit, edit own and some other permissions.

Comment: It's common for people who are new to the site to ask questions and then never accept an answer. As a result, their newer questions tend to be ignored. Reputation points are the currency of this site, and accepting an answer is like tipping a waiter/waitress :-) please valid my anwser if it was resolving your question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can see an exemple of this check in this file

> modules/mod_articles_latest/helper.php
>
> https://github.com/joomlagovbr/joomla-3.x/blob/master/modules/mod_articles_latest/helper.php

```
$authorised = JAccess::getAuthorisedViewLevels(JFactory::getUser()->get('id'));

if (in_array($item->access, $authorised))
{
    // We know that user has the privilege to view the article
    // do something here
}
```

Where $item is your article